# Как применить apply() на N столбцов для конкатинации в строку?

Tags: python, строки, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame вида:

```
     c1    c2    c3    ...    cN
0    1     1     0     ...    0
1    0     1     1     ...    0
2    0     0     1     ...    0
3    1     1     0     ...    1
```

Необходимо получить новый столбец, который являлся бы строкой вида `c1+c2+c3...+cN`.

Я делаю

```
df.loc[:, 'c1':'cN'].apply(lambda x: ???, axis=1)
```

Но не понимаю, как написать лямбду в этом случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
In [102]: df
Out[102]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0
2   0   0   1   0
3   1   1   0   1

In [103]: res = df.loc[:, "c1":"c4"].astype(str).T.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat())

In [104]: res
Out[104]:
0    1100
1    0110
2    0010
3    1101
dtype: object
```

или так (по совету @strawdog):

```
res = df.loc[:, "c1":"c4"].astype("str").apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(), axis=1)
```

Comment: да, и я получу сумму. А нужна строка

Comment: @Roman, пардон, невнимательно прочитал вопрос. Сейчас правильно?

Comment: да, работает, благодарю!

Comment: res = df.astype("str").apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(), axis=1) ?

Comment: @strawdog, да, спасибо, дополнил ответ